# Grab one for each id

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this at the moment:

```
SELECT de.id, d.name, de.title discos_events de
INNER JOIN places d ON (de.dID = d.id)
WHERE unix_timestamp(now()) > de.date
LIMIT 10
```

This shows me the latest 10 events.

So no matter if the 10 events comes from the same place (dID), it still shows 10..

Now I want it to show 1 latest event per place.

So if theres 20 events 10 is from dID 1 and 10 is from dID 2 it should output one event from each place, so that would be 2 events in total. And these two events are the latest one (unix_timestamp(now()) > de.date)

Comment: It shows you 10 random events that happend in the past, not the 10 latest.

Comment: @cularis latest is also in the past? how would you do 10 latest? the same way as the past?

Comment: You need to ORDER BY de.date DESC before you LIMIT your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have two events for the same id at the same date:

```
SELECT de.id, d.name, de.title 
FROM discos_events de INNER JOIN places d ON (de.dID = d.id) 
WHERE de.date = (SELECT MAX(t.date)
                 FROM disco_events t
                 WHERE t.dID = de.dID
                       AND unix_timestamp(now()) > t.date)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That `AND` was misplaced. Can you try again?